# how can i get the following figure using the for loop

Tags: procedural-programming

[image]

how can i get the following figure using the for loop.

```
n=5
For[i=1,i<5,i++,For[j=1,j<n,j++,A=(i+j)]]
A//MatrixForm
```

The code I found is above but not working.where is the mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to MMA SE! What the code above does is simply repeatedly overwrite the value of `A`. In each iteration of the loop, it evaluates `A = i + j`, so the `A` at the end of the loop is simply `i + j` for the last `i`, `j` in the loop.

You *could* do a `For` loop where you initialize `A` to a table, and then set different parts of `A`, e.g. `A[[i,j]] = "*"`. That's not advisable in Mathematica, but it would look like this:

```
n=6;
A = ConstantArray["", {n,n}];
For[i=1,i<=n,i++,For[j=1,j<=i,j++,A[[i,j]] = "*"]];
A // Grid
```

(Note an important change from the given code: we use `j <= i`, not `j <= n`.)

But it's far easier to simply use `Table` (or `Array`, for an alternative approach) to generate matrices, with a conditional statement in each entry that test if `i < j`:

```
Table[If[i < j, "", "*"], {i, 6}, {j, 6}] // Grid
```

Another way: you could also use `LowerTriangularize` on a 6 by 6 `ConstantArray` of `"*"`, and replace all the resulting `0`s in the upper triangle with `""`:

```
(LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray["*", {6, 6}]] /. (0 -> "")) // Grid
```

Comment: i understand you very well. i am much obligated. thank you very much

Comment: @hazal no problem, glad I could help, and of course feel free to let me know if you have any questions!